# Failing to push to repository on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I am trying to do some adjustments in one of my repos on GitHub. After doing the changes locally, I tried to push changes to the remote repository, but I got an error message for having a large file.
I removed the large file from the local repository and made a second commit. then tried to push the changes to the remote repository, but still get error messages. I tried with the following commands:

```
git push -f 
git push origin +HEAD
```

and I get this error message:

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Solameros/datasciencecoursera.git'
```

Any tips for how I can make a push to the remote repository without the large file?

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer! Glad I was able to help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will most likely need to `git rebase -i` and delete the commit that contains the large file. This is because even though you deleted the file in your latest commit a `git push` will push all commits, and that includes the large file.

I'm curious, how large is this file?

Comment: Thanks! it works now after rebase. It was a 126MB. That's strange, because I have been able to push a 260MB data to the same repo yesterday. Is there a max limit?

Comment: Not sure how you manage to push 260MB. The limit is 100MB per file. Do you mean you push 260MB of total data (multiple files?)

Comment: And thank you for accepting my answer! Glad I was able to help :-)

Comment: It was multiple files. That's probably the explanation. :-)